# Using Object key to make up a array

Tags: javascript

Considering follow code

```
const filterArray = ['a', 'b']
const objectToBeFilter = {
  a: {
    ab: 'ab',
    ac: 'ac',
    ad: 'ad'
  },
  b: {
    bb: 'bb',
    bc: 'bc',
    bd: 'bd'
  },
  c: {
    cb: 'cb',
    cc: 'cc',
    cd: 'cd'
  }
}

const resultWantToGet = [
  a: {
    ab: 'ab',
    ac: 'ac',
    ad: 'ad'
  },
  b: {
    bb: 'bb',
    bc: 'bc',
    bd: 'bd'
  }
]
```

`FilterArray` is a array to be used as a filter index, `objectToBeFilter` is a object which I want to handle. How to use filterArray to filter objectToBeFilter and then convert it to a array `resultWantToGet`?

Comment: You say you want an array, but the "array" you are showing has keys `a` and `b`, which is a syntax error. Do you want an array or new object?

Comment: The expected result is wrong

Comment: The resultWantToGet is a array contain many objects, doesn't it?

Comment: No, @yuanlai, an array of objects will look like this: `[ { ab: 'ab', ac: 'ac', ad: 'ad' }, { bb: 'bb', bc: 'bc', bd: 'bd' } ]` (without the keys). See answer below if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, it seem like you want an array of objects. You can do this simply with, which will give you the objects from `objectToBeFilter` keyed at `a` and `b` in an array:

```js
const filterArray = ['a', 'b']
const objectToBeFilter = {
  a: {
    ab: 'ab',
    ac: 'ac',
    ad: 'ad'
  },
  b: {
    bb: 'bb',
    bc: 'bc',
    bd: 'bd'
  },
  c: {
    cb: 'cb',
    cc: 'cc',
    cd: 'cd'
  }
}


let result = filterArray.map(key => objectToBeFilter[key])
console.log(result)
```

This looks different than your expected result because arrays don't have keys. If you want each item to be identified with a key, you probably want an object, but if you want an ordered collection, then an array is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` by `filterArray` and spread into a new object:

```js
const filterArray = ['a', 'b']
const objectToBeFilter = {
  a: {
    ab: 'ab',
    ac: 'ac',
    ad: 'ad'
  },
  b: {
    bb: 'bb',
    bc: 'bc',
    bd: 'bd'
  },
  c: {
    cb: 'cb',
    cc: 'cc',
    cd: 'cd'
  }
};
console.log({
  ...filterArray.map(key => ({ [key]: objectToBeFilter[key] }))
});
```

Or, if you don't want to create intermediate objects, use `reduce`:

```js
const filterArray = ['a', 'b']
const objectToBeFilter = {
  a: {
    ab: 'ab',
    ac: 'ac',
    ad: 'ad'
  },
  b: {
    bb: 'bb',
    bc: 'bc',
    bd: 'bd'
  },
  c: {
    cb: 'cb',
    cc: 'cc',
    cd: 'cd'
  }
};
console.log(filterArray.reduce((a, prop) => {
  a[prop] = objectToBeFilter[prop];
  return a;
}, {}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to loop and construct new object.

```js
const filterArray = ['a', 'b']
const objectToBeFilter = {
  a: {
    ab: 'ab',
    ac: 'ac',
    ad: 'ad'
  },
  b: {
    bb: 'bb',
    bc: 'bc',
    bd: 'bd'
  },
  c: {
    cb: 'cb',
    cc: 'cc',
    cd: 'cd'
  }
}

const resultWantToGet = filterArray.reduce((c, v) => {
  if (objectToBeFilter[v]) c[v] = objectToBeFilter[v]; //Check if the key exist in objectToBeFilter, if it does, assign to the accumulator. 
  return c;
}, {})

console.log(resultWantToGet);
```

Comment: Sorry for disturbing, how to convert resultWantToGet to a array?

Comment: @yuanlai, You need numerical indices?

Comment: Because I want to use length and resultWantToGet[index] like method, so I have this idea.

Comment: You can use `Object.values` to get all values. If you want to get the length:`Object.values(resultWantToGet).length`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code `Object.keys(objectToBeFilter)` get list of filtered object keys then filter keys that included in filter array `.filter(key => filterArray.includes(key))` then construct a new object with only the filtered properties `reduce((obj, key)`

```
const filterArray = ['a', 'b']
const objectToBeFilter = {
  a: {
    ab: 'ab',
    ac: 'ac',
    ad: 'ad'
  },
  b: {
    bb: 'bb',
    bc: 'bc',
    bd: 'bd'
  },
  c: {
    cb: 'cb',
    cc: 'cc',
    cd: 'cd'
  }
}

const resultWantToGet =  Object.keys(objectToBeFilter)
  .filter(key => filterArray.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = objectToBeFilter[key];
    return obj;}, {});

console.log(resultWantToGet)
```